# Why does this cameo character look like this?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

In Suicide Squad a blink and you miss it cameo by the Scarlet Speedster happens near the beginning. His lightning is blue. Why is it blue?  It's never blue in any medium where Barry Allen is shown.

Comment: It's also blue in [the Justice League trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIHH5-HVS9o), so at least they're being consistent, but I doubt there's any justification beyond "it looks cool, and different from existing Flashes".

Comment: Not even a mention or reference by Snyder or the new actor?

Comment: *"looks cool"* Or alternatively, more "realistic".

Comment: Because Barry is secretly zoom.

Comment: Red means less fast, blue means more faster !!! From The Flash TV series.